# I2C repeated start

Tags: i2c, attiny

I am trying to use [TC74 (or DS1621) temperature sensor](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/en010749) which comes with I2C interface. My I2C ISR is able so far to write command and config bytes to the chip. However I don't know how to instruct the ISR to jump to state `0x10` (repeated start) for a read operation. The read procedure is as following:

1. start bit by micro-controller (ATTINY48 in my case)
2. sending slave address+w (in state 0x8), ACK from slave
3. sending command byte to slave (in state 0x18), ACK from slave
4. at this point (state 0x28)  **ISR must send a repeated start and jump to state 0x10**
5. then sending Slave Adrress+R , ACK from slave
6. then in state 0x40 data will be read from slave, NACK to slave
7. in state 0x58 data is ready and copied to proper variable, stop bit will be transmitted.

I can set a flag every time I call the TC74 `read` function and check that flag inside the ISR, so instead of sending the stop bit after writing the data byte to the TC74, it will issue a repeated start bit. However I am not sure if this is the correct and standard method or not. Generally, in many states of I2C peripherals, the next state must be decided.

How should I instruct the ISR in each state to jump to the desired next state?